# Automatically Check if a webpage source code has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient

I am new to C#/WPF programming and I am trying to automatically update a local copy of a source code if the source code for a certain page has changed. Is there a way to check the source code say every other day without me having to go in manual do diff?

To get the source code for the website I have

```
Private bool getSourceCode(string UserInputSub)

    {
        //insert error catching..
        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) //Get source code of page.. user //enters URL
        {
            string s = webClient.DownloadString(UserInputSub);
            string fixedString = s.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
            string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string FilePath = desktopPath + "\\SourceCode.txt";
            System.IO.StreamWriter wr = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@FilePath);
            wr.Write(fixedString);//writes to script
            wr.Close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This only runs once the program is being runned. I would like it so the user does not have the run teh program for it to update the txt it produces.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to write a windows service that will fire once a day,  and do this for you. 
It'll add some complexity, but do what you want.

**edit**:
If you want this as part of the windows application, you can set a timer, or poll every x amount of time, but then your application needs to be open all the time for this to happen.

If you want to collect the data independently from the windows program who uses it, you'll have to have a separate service running in the background. Of course, you can have a simple console windows in the background that'll do it for you, but that so hackish that it should be illegal.

Comment: is there a way to wrap this in an Windows application. or is win apps and win services to seperate things?

Answer (score 0):

Add a timer to the project, set the interval to 86400000 ms(24 hs), and then in the tick event call your function,is not the best solution,better will be to add as a cron job or something, but if is a dedicated machine,sure it will work.